Display freezes on occasion with Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS, No keys work, SSH still responsive
I am running Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS on an 8GB Lenovo Ideapad 320-15IAP with 128GB SSD. Intermittently, the display will freeze. The system does not respond to mouse/keyboard input. Sound continues to play and I am able to log in via SSH. I have been unable to restart the display via SSH nor reboot the system via SSH. Attempts to do so make the system quite slow to respond. My only solution is to hold the power button down.
I've included the journal log from just before when I believe the issue started through my logging in via ssh.
Any suggestions? More info needed? Thank you.
My most frequently used desktop apps are Chrome and VS Code. This issue has persisted over two or three minor release updates of the 22.04.* series.




May 23 21:53:00 Artemis-LT gnome-session[2982]: gnome-session-binary[2982]: GnomeDesktop-WARNING: Failed to acquire idle monitor proxy: Timeout was r>
May 23 21:52:47 Artemis-LT gsd-power[3283]: Error setting property 'PowerSaveMode' on interface org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig: Timeout was reached (>
May 23 21:52:46 Artemis-LT gsd-power[3283]: Failed to acquire idle monitor proxy: Timeout was reached
May 23 21:52:46 Artemis-LT gnome-session-binary[2982]: GnomeDesktop-WARNING: Failed to acquire idle monitor proxy: Timeout was reached
May 23 21:52:46 Artemis-LT gnome-session[2982]: gnome-session-binary[2982]: GnomeDesktop-WARNING: Failed to acquire idle monitor proxy: Timeout was r>
May 23 21:52:24 Artemis-LT wpa_supplicant[535]: wlp3s0: WPA: Group rekeying completed with 54:83:3a:94:14:23 [GTK=TKIP]
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel:  ? asm_exc_page_fault+0x27/0x30
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel:  ? exc_page_fault+0x83/0x1b0
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel:  ? do_user_addr_fault+0x31d/0x6b0
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel:  ? page_fault_oops+0x99/0x1b0
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel:  ? __die+0x24/0x80
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel:  ? show_regs+0x6d/0x80
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel:  <TASK>
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: Call Trace:
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: CR2: 00000000421c9cc9 CR3: 0000000156642000 CR4: 00000000003506e0
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff90bc77c80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: R13: ffffffffc0dd2d28 R14: ffffffffc0dc71ea R15: ffff9ef34d33a308
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 110aadf5f3267adc R12: ffffffffc0dd2cf8
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: RBP: ffff9ef34d33a260 R08: ffff9ef34d33a300 R09: ffffffffc0dc9000
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: RDX: 0000000000000001 RSI: 0000000000000006 RDI: af2975851885dac6
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: RAX: ffffffffc0dd3418 RBX: 0000000000000392 RCX: 00000000421c9cc9
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: RSP: 0000:ffff9ef34d33a218 EFLAGS: 00010007
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: Code: fe 72 40 49 39 fb 73 3b 49 89 fb 41 89 d2 83 c2 01 48 83 c0 18 39 d3 74 46 66 83 78 06 00 48 8b 78 08 74 ea >
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: RIP: 0010:find_kallsyms_symbol+0x13e/0x250
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: Workqueue: rtl8821ae_pci rtl_c2hcmd_wq_callback [rtlwifi]
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: Hardware name: LENOVO 80XR/LNVNB161216, BIOS 5RCN36WW 08/06/2018
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: CPU: 1 PID: 9085 Comm: kworker/1:0 Not tainted 6.5.0-35-generic #35~22.04.1-Ubuntu
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: Oops: 0000 [#3] PREEMPT SMP NOPTI
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: PGD 0 P4D 0 
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: #PF: error_code(0x0000) - not-present page
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: #PF: supervisor read access in kernel mode
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: BUG: unable to handle page fault for address: 00000000421c9cc9
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel:  ? asm_exc_page_fault+0x27/0x30
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel:  ? exc_page_fault+0x83/0x1b0
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel:  ? do_user_addr_fault+0x31d/0x6b0
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel:  ? page_fault_oops+0x99/0x1b0
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel:  ? __die+0x24/0x80
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel:  ? show_regs+0x6d/0x80
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel:  <TASK>
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: Call Trace:
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: CR2: 00000000421c9cc9 CR3: 0000000156642000 CR4: 00000000003506e0
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff90bc77c80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: R13: ffffffffc0dd2d28 R14: ffffffffc0dc71eb R15: ffff9ef34d33ac48
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 110aadf5f3267adc R12: ffffffffc0dd2cf8
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: RBP: ffff9ef34d33aba0 R08: ffff9ef34d33ac40 R09: ffffffffc0dc9000
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: RDX: 0000000000000001 RSI: 0000000000000006 RDI: af2975851885dac6
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: RAX: ffffffffc0dd3418 RBX: 0000000000000392 RCX: 00000000421c9cc9
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: RSP: 0000:ffff9ef34d33ab58 EFLAGS: 00010007
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: Code: fe 72 40 49 39 fb 73 3b 49 89 fb 41 89 d2 83 c2 01 48 83 c0 18 39 d3 74 46 66 83 78 06 00 48 8b 78 08 74 ea >
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: RIP: 0010:find_kallsyms_symbol+0x13e/0x250
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: Workqueue: rtl8821ae_pci rtl_c2hcmd_wq_callback [rtlwifi]
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: Hardware name: LENOVO 80XR/LNVNB161216, BIOS 5RCN36WW 08/06/2018
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: CPU: 1 PID: 9085 Comm: kworker/1:0 Not tainted 6.5.0-35-generic #35~22.04.1-Ubuntu
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: Oops: 0000 [#2] PREEMPT SMP NOPTI
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: PGD 0 P4D 0 
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: #PF: error_code(0x0000) - not-present page
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: #PF: supervisor read access in kernel mode
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: BUG: unable to handle page fault for address: 00000000421c9cc9
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel:  ? asm_exc_page_fault+0x27/0x30
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel:  ? exc_page_fault+0x83/0x1b0
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel:  ? do_user_addr_fault+0x31d/0x6b0
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel:  ? page_fault_oops+0x99/0x1b0
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel:  ? __die+0x24/0x80
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel:  ? show_regs+0x6d/0x80
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel:  <TASK>
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: Call Trace:
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: CR2: 00000000421c9cc9 CR3: 0000000156642000 CR4: 00000000003506e0
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff90bc77c80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: R13: ffffffffc0dd2d28 R14: ffffffffc0dc71ec R15: ffff9ef34d33b588
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 110aadf5f3267adc R12: ffffffffc0dd2cf8
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: RBP: ffff9ef34d33b4e0 R08: ffff9ef34d33b580 R09: ffffffffc0dc9000
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: RDX: 0000000000000001 RSI: 0000000000000006 RDI: af2975851885dac6
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: RAX: ffffffffc0dd3418 RBX: 0000000000000392 RCX: 00000000421c9cc9
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: RSP: 0000:ffff9ef34d33b498 EFLAGS: 00010007
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: Code: fe 72 40 49 39 fb 73 3b 49 89 fb 41 89 d2 83 c2 01 48 83 c0 18 39 d3 74 46 66 83 78 06 00 48 8b 78 08 74 ea >
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: RIP: 0010:find_kallsyms_symbol+0x13e/0x250
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: Workqueue: rtl8821ae_pci rtl_c2hcmd_wq_callback [rtlwifi]
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: Hardware name: LENOVO 80XR/LNVNB161216, BIOS 5RCN36WW 08/06/2018
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: CPU: 1 PID: 9085 Comm: kworker/1:0 Not tainted 6.5.0-35-generic #35~22.04.1-Ubuntu
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: Oops: 0000 [#1] PREEMPT SMP NOPTI
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: PGD 0 P4D 0 
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: #PF: error_code(0x0000) - not-present page
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: #PF: supervisor read access in kernel mode
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: BUG: unable to handle page fault for address: 00000000421c9cc9
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel:  __ubsan_handle_load_invalid_value+0xce/0x120
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel:  dump_stack+0x10/0x20
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel:  dump_stack_lvl+0x48/0x70
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel:  <TASK>
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: Call Trace:
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: Workqueue: rtl8821ae_pci rtl_c2hcmd_wq_callback [rtlwifi]
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: Hardware name: LENOVO 80XR/LNVNB161216, BIOS 5RCN36WW 08/06/2018
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: CPU: 1 PID: 9085 Comm: kworker/1:0 Not tainted 6.5.0-35-generic #35~22.04.1-Ubuntu
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: load of value 217 is not a valid value for type '_Bool'
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: UBSAN: invalid-load in /build/linux-hwe-6.5-X9ca7v/linux-hwe-6.5-6.5.0/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/btcoex>
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: ================================================================================
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: ================================================================================
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel:  </TASK>
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel:  ret_from_fork_asm+0x1b/0x30
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel:  ? __pfx_kthread+0x10/0x10
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel:  ret_from_fork+0x47/0x70
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel:  ? __pfx_kthread+0x10/0x10
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel:  kthread+0xf2/0x120
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel:  ? __pfx_worker_thread+0x10/0x10
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel:  worker_thread+0x50/0x3f0
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel:  process_one_work+0x240/0x450
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel:  rtl_c2hcmd_wq_callback+0x3c/0x80 [rtlwifi]
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel:  rtl_c2h_content_parsing.isra.0+0x66/0x110 [rtlwifi]
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel:  rtl_btc_btinfo_notify+0x1d/0x40 [btcoexist]
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel:  exhalbtc_bt_info_notify+0xc8/0xe0 [btcoexist]
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel:  ex_btc8821a2ant_bt_info_notify+0x458/0x520 [btcoexist]
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel:  __ubsan_handle_out_of_bounds+0xc6/0x110
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel:  dump_stack+0x10/0x20
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel:  dump_stack_lvl+0x48/0x70
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel:  <TASK>
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: Call Trace:
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: Workqueue: rtl8821ae_pci rtl_c2hcmd_wq_callback [rtlwifi]
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: Hardware name: LENOVO 80XR/LNVNB161216, BIOS 5RCN36WW 08/06/2018
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: CPU: 1 PID: 9085 Comm: kworker/1:0 Not tainted 6.5.0-35-generic #35~22.04.1-Ubuntu
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: index 10 is out of range for type 'u8 [10]'
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bounds in /build/linux-hwe-6.5-X9ca7v/linux-hwe-6.5-6.5.0/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/r>
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: ================================================================================
May 23 21:38:04 Artemis-LT gnome-shell[3023]: Window manager warning: 0xa00004 appears to be one of the offending windows with a timestamp of 7183023>
May 23 21:38:04 Artemis-LT gnome-shell[3023]: Window manager warning: last_user_time (7183023) is greater than comparison timestamp (7182998).  This >
May 23 21:38:04 Artemis-LT gnome-shell[3846]: Key repeat discarded, Wayland compositor doesn't seem to be processing events fast enough!
May 23 21:38:04 Artemis-LT gnome-shell[3846]: Key repeat discarded, Wayland compositor doesn't seem to be processing events fast enough!
May 23 21:30:16 Artemis-LT systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Run anacron jobs being skipped.
May 23 21:30:01 Artemis-LT CRON[8838]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
May 23 21:30:01 Artemis-LT CRON[8839]: (root) CMD ([ -x /etc/init.d/anacron ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d anacron >
May 23 21:30:01 Artemis-LT CRON[8838]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
May 23 21:28:03 Artemis-LT wpa_supplicant[535]: wlp3s0: WPA: Group rekeying completed with 54:83:3a:94:14:23 [GTK=TKIP]
May 23 21:22:30 Artemis-LT wpa_supplicant[535]: wlp3s0: WPA: Group rekeying completed with 54:83:3a:94:14:23 [GTK=TKIP]
May 23 21:22:30 Artemis-LT wpa_supplicant[535]: wlp3s0: WPA: Group rekeying completed with 54:83:3a:94:14:23 [GTK=TKIP]
May 23 21:22:30 Artemis-LT wpa_supplicant[535]: wlp3s0: WPA: Group rekeying completed with 54:83:3a:94:14:23 [GTK=TKIP]
May 23 21:21:16 Artemis-LT pulseaudio[2876]: Battery Level: 90%
May 23 21:21:08 Artemis-LT Thunar[8491]: thunar-volman: Unsupported input device type "/dev/input/event11".
May 23 21:21:06 Artemis-LT Thunar[8482]: thunar-volman: Unsupported input device type "(null)".
May 23 21:21:06 Artemis-LT pulseaudio[2876]: Battery Level: 80%
May 23 21:21:05 Artemis-LT pulseaudio[2876]: Battery Level: 90%
May 23 21:21:04 Artemis-LT systemd-logind[532]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event11 (cluckngoods (AVRCP))
May 23 21:21:04 Artemis-LT kernel: input: cluckngoods (AVRCP) as /devices/virtual/input/input11
May 23 21:21:04 Artemis-LT pulseaudio[2876]: org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get /org/bluez/hci0/dev_41_42_3B_97_08_57/sep1/fd0 Volume failed: org.fr>
May 23 21:21:04 Artemis-LT rtkit-daemon[789]: Supervising 7 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
May 23 21:21:04 Artemis-LT rtkit-daemon[789]: Successfully made thread 8481 of process 2876 owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
May 23 21:21:04 Artemis-LT rtkit-daemon[789]: Supervising 6 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
May 23 21:21:04 Artemis-LT bluetoothd[512]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_41_42_3B_97_08_57/sep1/fd0: fd(42) ready
May 23 21:21:04 Artemis-LT ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com[3023]: unable to update icon for blueman
May 23 21:21:03 Artemis-LT systemd[2865]: Reached target Bluetooth.
May 23 21:21:03 Artemis-LT ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com[3023]: unable to update icon for blueman
May 23 21:21:03 Artemis-LT ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com[3023]: unable to update icon for blueman
May 23 21:21:03 Artemis-LT ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com[3023]: unable to update icon for blueman
May 23 21:17:01 Artemis-LT CRON[8405]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
May 23 21:17:01 Artemis-LT CRON[8406]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
May 23 21:17:01 Artemis-LT CRON[8405]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
May 23 21:13:36 Artemis-LT upowerd[950]: energy 26.500000 bigger than full 26.400000
May 23 21:11:46 Artemis-LT gnome-shell[3023]: Window manager warning: 0xa00004 appears to be one of the offending windows with a timestamp of 5604934>
May 23 21:11:46 Artemis-LT gnome-shell[3023]: Window manager warning: last_user_time (5604934) is greater than comparison timestamp (5604931).  This >
May 23 21:11:46 Artemis-LT gnome-shell[3846]: Key repeat discarded, Wayland compositor doesn't seem to be processing events fast enough!
May 23 21:11:46 Artemis-LT gnome-shell[3846]: Key repeat discarded, Wayland compositor doesn't seem to be processing events fast enough!
May 23 21:11:46 Artemis-LT gnome-shell[3846]: Key repeat discarded, Wayland compositor doesn't seem to be processing events fast enough!
May 23 21:11:45 Artemis-LT gnome-shell[3846]: Key repeat discarded, Wayland compositor doesn't seem to be processing events fast enough!
May 23 21:11:45 Artemis-LT gnome-shell[3846]: Key repeat discarded, Wayland compositor doesn't seem to be processing events fast enough!
May 23 21:11:45 Artemis-LT gnome-shell[3846]: Key repeat discarded, Wayland compositor doesn't seem to be processing events fast enough!
May 23 21:11:45 Artemis-LT gnome-shell[3846]: Key repeat discarded, Wayland compositor doesn't seem to be processing events fast enough!
May 23 21:11:45 Artemis-LT gnome-shell[3846]: Key repeat discarded, Wayland compositor doesn't seem to be processing events fast enough!
May 23 21:05:45 Artemis-LT google-chrome.desktop[3738]: [3962:3967:0523/210545.847616:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(879)] handshake failed; returne>
May 23 21:05:37 Artemis-LT google-chrome.desktop[3738]: [3962:3967:0523/210537.910336:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(879)] handshake failed; returne>
May 23 21:05:25 Artemis-LT google-chrome.desktop[3738]: [3962:3967:0523/210525.599227:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(879)] handshake failed; returne>
May 23 21:05:25 Artemis-LT google-chrome.desktop[3738]: [3962:3967:0523/210525.584174:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(879)] handshake failed; returne>
May 23 20:58:08 Artemis-LT wpa_supplicant[535]: wlp3s0: WPA: Group rekeying completed with 54:83:3a:94:14:23 [GTK=TKIP]
May 23 20:52:38 Artemis-LT wpa_supplicant[535]: wlp3s0: WPA: Group rekeying completed with 54:83:3a:94:14:23 [GTK=TKIP]
May 23 20:45:54 Artemis-LT google-chrome.desktop[3738]: [3962:3967:0523/204554.845531:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(879)] handshake failed; returne>
May 23 20:35:22 Artemis-LT google-chrome.desktop[3738]: Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file: No such file: (null)
May 23 20:32:08 Artemis-LT systemd[1]: anacron.service: Deactivated successfully.
May 23 20:32:08 Artemis-LT anacron[7215]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
May 23 20:32:08 Artemis-LT systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
May 23 20:32:08 Artemis-LT anacron[7215]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2024-05-23
May 23 20:30:01 Artemis-LT CRON[7023]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
May 23 20:30:01 Artemis-LT CRON[7024]: (root) CMD ([ -x /etc/init.d/anacron ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d anacron >
May 23 20:30:01 Artemis-LT CRON[7023]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
May 23 20:29:34 Artemis-LT google-chrome.desktop[3738]: [3724:3724:0523/202934.672278:ERROR:atom_cache.cc(229)] Add chromium/from-privileged to kAtom>
May 23 20:28:15 Artemis-LT wpa_supplicant[535]: wlp3s0: WPA: Group rekeying completed with 54:83:3a:94:14:23 [GTK=TKIP]
May 23 20:24:38 Artemis-LT google-chrome.desktop[3738]: [3960:3960:0523/202438.382526:ERROR:shared_image_manager.cc(222)] SharedImageManager::Produce>
May 23 20:22:43 Artemis-LT wpa_supplicant[535]: wlp3s0: WPA: Group rekeying completed with 54:83:3a:94:14:23 [GTK=TKIP]
May 23 20:22:43 Artemis-LT wpa_supplicant[535]: wlp3s0: WPA: Group rekeying completed with 54:83:3a:94:14:23 [GTK=TKIP]
May 23 20:18:10 Artemis-LT kernel: perf: interrupt took too long (6198 > 6197), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 32250
May 23 20:17:01 Artemis-LT CRON[6400]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
May 23 20:17:01 Artemis-LT CRON[6401]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
May 23 20:17:01 Artemis-LT CRON[6400]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
May 23 20:05:18 Artemis-LT kernel: perf: interrupt took too long (4958 > 4957), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 40250
May 23 20:01:16 Artemis-LT google-chrome.desktop[3738]: [3962:3967:0523/200116.521241:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(879)] handshake failed; returne>
May 23 20:00:24 Artemis-LT kernel: perf: interrupt took too long (3966 > 3958), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 50250
May 23 19:59:52 Artemis-LT google-chrome.desktop[3738]: [3962:3967:0523/195952.390884:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(879)] handshake failed; returne>
May 23 19:59:39 Artemis-LT google-chrome.desktop[3738]: [3962:3967:0523/195939.333703:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(879)] handshake failed; returne>
May 23 19:59:25 Artemis-LT google-chrome.desktop[3738]: [3962:3967:0523/195925.627891:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(879)] handshake failed; returne>
May 23 19:59:25 Artemis-LT google-chrome.desktop[3738]: [3962:3967:0523/195925.572946:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(879)] handshake failed; returne>
May 23 19:58:21 Artemis-LT wpa_supplicant[535]: wlp3s0: WPA: Group rekeying completed with 54:83:3a:94:14:23 [GTK=TKIP]
May 23 19:58:21 Artemis-LT wpa_supplicant[535]: wlp3s0: WPA: Group rekeying completed with 54:83:3a:94:14:23 [GTK=TKIP]
May 23 19:57:43 Artemis-LT kernel: perf: interrupt took too long (3167 > 3161), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 63000
May 23 19:56:00 Artemis-LT kernel: perf: interrupt took too long (2529 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 79000
May 23 19:55:45 Artemis-LT google-chrome.desktop[3738]: Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file: No such file: (null)
May 23 19:55:26 Artemis-LT dbus-daemon[2888]: [session uid=1000 pid=2888] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.DejaDup'
May 23 19:55:26 Artemis-LT dbus-daemon[2888]: [session uid=1000 pid=2888] Activating service name='org.gnome.DejaDup' requested by ':1.28' (uid=1000 >
May 23 19:54:02 Artemis-LT google-chrome.desktop[3738]: [3962:3967:0523/195402.044164:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(879)] handshake failed; returne>
May 23 19:53:59 Artemis-LT google-chrome.desktop[3738]: Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file: No such file: (null)
May 23 19:53:28 Artemis-LT systemd[1]: Finished Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
May 23 19:53:28 Artemis-LT systemd[1]: systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service: Deactivated successfully.
May 23 19:53:28 Artemis-LT systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...
May 23 19:52:58 Artemis-LT systemd[2865]: Started Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
May 23 19:52:48 Artemis-LT wpa_supplicant[535]: wlp3s0: WPA: Group rekeying completed with 54:83:3a:94:14:23 [GTK=TKIP]
May 23 19:52:30 Artemis-LT systemd[2865]: Started VTE child process 4513 launched by gnome-terminal-server process 4495.
May 23 19:52:30 Artemis-LT systemd[2865]: Started GNOME Terminal Server.
May 23 19:52:30 Artemis-LT dbus-daemon[2888]: [session uid=1000 pid=2888] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Terminal'
May 23 19:52:30 Artemis-LT systemd[2865]: Starting GNOME Terminal Server...
May 23 19:52:30 Artemis-LT systemd[2865]: Created slice Slice /app/org.gnome.Terminal.
May 23 19:52:30 Artemis-LT dbus-daemon[2888]: [session uid=1000 pid=2888] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.Terminal' unit='gnome-termi>
May 23 19:52:29 Artemis-LT systemd[2865]: Started Application launched by gsd-media-keys.
May 23 19:52:05 Artemis-LT ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com[3023]: unable to update icon for livepatch
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel:  rtl_c2h_content_parsing.isra.0+0x66/0x110 [rtlwifi]
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel:  rtl_btc_btinfo_notify+0x1d/0x40 [btcoexist]
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel:  exhalbtc_bt_info_notify+0xc8/0xe0 [btcoexist]
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel:  ex_btc8821a2ant_bt_info_notify+0x458/0x520 [btcoexist]
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel:  __ubsan_handle_out_of_bounds+0xc6/0x110
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel:  dump_stack+0x10/0x20
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel:  dump_stack_lvl+0x48/0x70
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel:  <TASK>
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: Call Trace:
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: Workqueue: rtl8821ae_pci rtl_c2hcmd_wq_callback [rtlwifi]
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: Hardware name: LENOVO 80XR/LNVNB161216, BIOS 5RCN36WW 08/06/2018
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: CPU: 1 PID: 9085 Comm: kworker/1:0 Not tainted 6.5.0-35-generic #35~22.04.1-Ubuntu
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: index 10 is out of range for type 'u8 [10]'
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bounds in /build/linux-hwe-6.5-X9ca7v/linux-hwe-6.5-6.5.0/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/r>
May 23 21:42:58 Artemis-LT kernel: ================================================================================
May 23 21:38:04 Artemis-LT gnome-shell[3023]: Window manager warning: 0xa00004 appears to be one of the offending windows with a timestamp of 7183023>
May 23 21:38:04 Artemis-LT gnome-shell[3023]: Window manager warning: last_user_time (7183023) is greater than comparison timestamp (7182998).  This >
May 23 21:38:04 Artemis-LT gnome-shell[3846]: Key repeat discarded, Wayland compositor doesn't seem to be processing events fast enough!
May 23 21:38:04 Artemis-LT gnome-shell[3846]: Key repeat discarded, Wayland compositor doesn't seem to be processing events fast enough!
May 23 21:30:16 Artemis-LT systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Run anacron jobs being skipped.
May 23 21:30:01 Artemis-LT CRON[8838]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
May 23 21:30:01 Artemis-LT CRON[8839]: (root) CMD ([ -x /etc/init.d/anacron ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d anacron >
May 23 21:30:01 Artemis-LT CRON[8838]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
May 23 21:28:03 Artemis-LT wpa_supplicant[535]: wlp3s0: WPA: Group rekeying completed with 54:83:3a:94:14:23 [GTK=TKIP]
May 23 21:22:30 Artemis-LT wpa_supplicant[535]: wlp3s0: WPA: Group rekeying completed with 54:83:3a:94:14:23 [GTK=TKIP]
May 23 21:22:30 Artemis-LT wpa_supplicant[535]: wlp3s0: WPA: Group rekeying completed with 54:83:3a:94:14:23 [GTK=TKIP]
May 23 21:22:30 Artemis-LT wpa_supplicant[535]: wlp3s0: WPA: Group rekeying completed with 54:83:3a:94:14:23 [GTK=TKIP]
May 23 21:21:16 Artemis-LT pulseaudio[2876]: Battery Level: 90%
May 23 21:21:08 Artemis-LT Thunar[8491]: thunar-volman: Unsupported input device type "/dev/input/event11".
May 23 21:21:06 Artemis-LT Thunar[8482]: thunar-volman: Unsupported input device type "(null)".
May 23 21:21:06 Artemis-LT pulseaudio[2876]: Battery Level: 80%
May 23 21:21:05 Artemis-LT pulseaudio[2876]: Battery Level: 90%
May 23 21:21:04 Artemis-LT systemd-logind[532]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event11 (cluckngoods (AVRCP))
May 23 21:21:04 Artemis-LT kernel: input: cluckngoods (AVRCP) as /devices/virtual/input/input11
May 23 21:21:04 Artemis-LT pulseaudio[2876]: org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get /org/bluez/hci0/dev_41_42_3B_97_08_57/sep1/fd0 Volume failed: org.fr>
May 23 21:21:04 Artemis-LT rtkit-daemon[789]: Supervising 7 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
May 23 21:21:04 Artemis-LT rtkit-daemon[789]: Successfully made thread 8481 of process 2876 owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
May 23 21:21:04 Artemis-LT rtkit-daemon[789]: Supervising 6 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
May 23 21:21:04 Artemis-LT bluetoothd[512]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_41_42_3B_97_08_57/sep1/fd0: fd(42) ready
May 23 21:21:04 Artemis-LT ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com[3023]: unable to update icon for blueman
May 23 21:21:03 Artemis-LT systemd[2865]: Reached target Bluetooth.
May 23 21:21:03 Artemis-LT ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com[3023]: unable to update icon for blueman
May 23 21:21:03 Artemis-LT ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com[3023]: unable to update icon for blueman
May 23 21:21:03 Artemis-LT ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com[3023]: unable to update icon for blueman
May 23 21:17:01 Artemis-LT CRON[8405]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
May 23 21:17:01 Artemis-LT CRON[8406]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
May 23 21:17:01 Artemis-LT CRON[8405]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
May 23 21:13:36 Artemis-LT upowerd[950]: energy 26.500000 bigger than full 26.400000
May 23 21:11:46 Artemis-LT gnome-shell[3023]: Window manager warning: 0xa00004 appears to be one of the offending windows with a timestamp of 5604934>
May 23 21:11:46 Artemis-LT gnome-shell[3023]: Window manager warning: last_user_time (5604934) is greater than comparison timestamp (5604931).  This >
May 23 21:11:46 Artemis-LT gnome-shell[3846]: Key repeat discarded, Wayland compositor doesn't seem to be processing events fast enough!
May 23 21:11:46 Artemis-LT gnome-shell[3846]: Key repeat discarded, Wayland compositor doesn't seem to be processing events fast enough!
May 23 21:11:46 Artemis-LT gnome-shell[3846]: Key repeat discarded, Wayland compositor doesn't seem to be processing events fast enough!
May 23 21:11:45 Artemis-LT gnome-shell[3846]: Key repeat discarded, Wayland compositor doesn't seem to be processing events fast enough!
May 23 21:11:45 Artemis-LT gnome-shell[3846]: Key repeat discarded, Wayland compositor doesn't seem to be processing events fast enough!
May 23 21:11:45 Artemis-LT gnome-shell[3846]: Key repeat discarded, Wayland compositor doesn't seem to be processing events fast enough!
May 23 21:11:45 Artemis-LT gnome-shell[3846]: Key repeat discarded, Wayland compositor doesn't seem to be processing events fast enough!
May 23 21:11:45 Artemis-LT gnome-shell[3846]: Key repeat discarded, Wayland compositor doesn't seem to be processing events fast enough!
May 23 21:05:45 Artemis-LT google-chrome.desktop[3738]: [3962:3967:0523/210545.847616:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(879)] handshake failed; returne>
May 23 21:05:37 Artemis-LT google-chrome.desktop[3738]: [3962:3967:0523/210537.910336:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(879)] handshake failed; returne>
May 23 21:05:25 Artemis-LT google-chrome.desktop[3738]: [3962:3967:0523/210525.599227:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(879)] handshake failed; returne>
May 23 21:05:25 Artemis-LT google-chrome.desktop[3738]: [3962:3967:0523/210525.584174:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(879)] handshake failed; returne>



https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1982560?
